# How to make element 0 optional?

Tags: typescript, option-type

Currently I have this:

```
type ArrayPlusRestCount<T> = [T & {restCount: number} | undefined, ...T[]];
```

Any ideas how to make element 0 to not be required because currently something like:

```
const so: ArrayPlusRestCount<number> = [];
```

fails with:

> Property '0' is missing in type '[]' but required in type '[number & { restCount: number; }, ...number[]]'

Answer (score 2):

You can make the element optional using `?`

```
type ArrayPlusRestCount<T> = [(T & {restCount: number} | undefined)?, ...T[]];

const so: ArrayPlusRestCount<number> = []
```

Comment: I feel so dumb.

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions Don't the `?` for tuples is a relative new addition to TS :)

Comment: I would have expected the `| undefined` to be enough, really. So i do not think this solution is obvious.

Comment: @H.B. `| undefined` is never enough to make something optional unfortunately

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir: I was pretty sure that e.g. for normal properties the syntax `prop?: string` was equivalent to `prop: string | undefined`, but you are right, the type of the property will be the same but only the property with `?` will be optional.

Comment: @H.B. I personally think it is mostly an oversight, unions were introduced way after `?`, so my guess is `?`  was never retrofitted to take `| undefined` into account. I'm pretty sure there is a GitHub issue about this